# Extract substring after delimiter using GNU awk or awk

Tags: awk, sed, string, cut

I would like to extract substring after *colon* delimiter for my practical needs using GNU awk utility.
For example I can extract the temperature of hdd value using `cut` as follows

```
hddtemp /dev/sda | cut -d ':' -f3
```

The same example written in `sed`

```
hddtemp /dev/sda | sed 's/.*\://'
```

For glory of Saint Completeness and GNU Trinity (awk, cut, sed)
I wonder, can GNU `awk` do such thing?

**Sample input**: `/dev/sda: ST500LT012-9WS142: 47°C`

**Required output**: `47°C`

Comment: Please post sample input and required output

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS, done!

Comment: `... |awk '{ print $NF }'`

Comment: @don_crissti, Yep!

`awk -F ":" '{print $NF}'` also works well.

But in that topic the answer wasn't accepted.

Comment: (Sadly...) The best answer isn't always the accepted one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the command

```
echo "/dev/sda: ST500LT012-9WS142: 47°C" | awk -F ":" '{print $3}'
```

output:

```
 echo "/dev/sda: ST500LT012-9WS142: 47°C" | awk -F ":" '{print $3}'
 47°C
```